# Image Slider like instagram?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, slider, pinchzoom

I want to create image slider like instagram which have pinch to zoom functionality. I have image slider in UITableviewCell after pinch of image i want to zoom the image on full screen like instagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Horizontal collection view for image slider with paging enabled. And for zoom functionality, you can add a scroll view inside the collection view cell. The view hierarchy should be like  - CollectionView cell -> ScrollView -> Image view.

For enabling zoom use GestureRecognizer.

Let me know if you have any confusion.